# Confusion with SKlearn Precision-Recall Curve computation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

Following is the snippet from sci-kit [pr-curve](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve) computation.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
>>> y_true = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
>>> y_scores = np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
>>> precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(
...     y_true, y_scores)
>>> precision  
array([ 0.66...,  0.5       ,  1.        ,  1.        ])
>>> recall
array([ 1. ,  0.5,  0.5,  0. ])
>>> thresholds
array([ 0.35,  0.4 ,  0.8 ])
```

Doubts:

Why are thresholds only 3 while precision and recall given are 4. As one can clearly see the threshold of 0.1 is left out. And the computation starts from threshold 0.35 and more.

Answer (score 2):

The thresholds only go low enough to attain 100% recall.  The idea being that you generally wouldn't set a lower threshold as it would introduce unnecessary false positives.

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py

```
   # stop when full recall attained
   # and reverse the outputs so recall is decreasing
    last_ind = tps.searchsorted(tps[-1])            
    sl = slice(last_ind, None, -1)
    return np.r_[precision[sl], 1], np.r_[recall[sl], 0], thresholds[sl]
```

Comment: Thank you.  It makes sense. Also, I guess you can add why is there no threshold for the last set of precision and recall- 'The last precision and recall values are 1. and 0. respectively and do not have a corresponding threshold.  This ensures that the graph starts on the x-axis'. Moreover, if precision 1, recall 0 is not possible, and vice-versa.